# ReactJS Hooks dependency an async operation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, indexeddb

So I have a hook that on mount, reads data from an indexedDB and stores that data in its internal state

The problem that I have, is that the indexedDB data gets changed from another component (added/removed), and I need to react to those changes in this hook. I'm not 100% familiar with hooks and how this would be done, but the first thought would be to have as hook dependency the value from the indexedDB.

HOWEVER, the reading of the data from the indexedDB is an async operation and the hook dependency would be a.. promise.

So basically, the flow is as follows:

1. Component 1 calls the hook like so:

```
  const eventItems = useEventListItems({
    sortBy,
    sortGroupedBy,
    eventTimestamp,
    events,
    assets,
    touchedEventIds,
    unsyncedEvents, // <--- this is the one that we need
    order,
  });
```

2. The `useEventListItems` hook, on mount, reads the data from the indexed DB, stores it in its internal state and returns it:

```
  const { readUnsyncedEvents } = useDebriefStore();
  const [unsyncedEvents, setUnsyncedEvents] = useState<number[]>([]);
  useEffectAsync(async () => {
    const storedUnsyncedEventIds = await readUnsyncedEvents<number[]>();
    if (storedUnsyncedEventIds?.data) {
      setUnsyncedEvents(storedUnsyncedEventIds.data);
    }
  }, [setUnsyncedEvents]);
```

where `readUnsyncedEvents` is:

```
export const readUnsyncedEvents = <T>(type: Type): Promise<DebriefStoreEntry<T>> =>
  debriefStore
    .get(type)
    .then((entry) => entry && { data: entry.data, timestamp: entry.timestamp });
```

3. The unsyncedEvents from the indexedDB are then changed from another component.
4. What *should* happen now, is that the `useEventListItems` hook should listen to the changes in the IDB and update the unsyncedEvents in its internal state, passing them to the component that uses this hook. How would I achieve this?

My first thought was to have something like this in the useEventListItems hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setUnsyncedEvents(..newValueFromIdb);
}, [ await readUnsyncedEvents()]);
```

but that won't work since it'll be a promise. Is there anyway I can have as hook dependency, a value returned by an async operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Context API to refetch the data from IDB.

The idea here is to create a context with a counter variable which will be updated after each IDB update operation. And `useEventListItems` hook will read that counter variable from context and trigger the `useEffect` hook.

```
export const IDBContext = React.createContext({
  readFromIDB: null,
  setReadFromIDB: () => {}
});

export const IDBContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [readFromIDB, setReadFromIDB] = useState(0);
  return (
    <IDBContext.Provider value={{ readFromIDB, setReadFromIDB }}>
      {children}
    </IDBContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

This is how your `useEventListItems` will look like.

```
const { readUnsyncedEvents } = useDebriefStore();
const [unsyncedEvents, setUnsyncedEvents] = useState<number[]>([]);

const {readFromIDB} = useContext(IDBContext); // this variable will be updated after each IDB update.

useEffectAsync(async () => {
  const storedUnsyncedEventIds = await readUnsyncedEvents<number[]>();
  if (storedUnsyncedEventIds?.data) {
    setUnsyncedEvents(storedUnsyncedEventIds.data);
  }
}, [readFromIDB,setUnsyncedEvents]); // added that to dependency array to trigger the hook on value change.
```

And here are the components:

```
const IDBUpdateComponent = ()=>{
const {readFromIDB,setReadFromIDB} = useContext(IDBContext);
  const updateIDB = ()=>{
    someIDBUpdateOpetation().then(res=>{
      setReadFromIDB(readFromIDB+1) // update the context after IDB update is successful.
    }).catch(e=>{})
  }

  return(
    <div>IDBUpdateComponent</div>
  );
}

const IDBConsumerComponent = ()=>{
  return (
    <div>IDBConsumerComponent</div>
  )
}
```

Just make sure that both the components are wrapped inside the context so that they can access the values.

```
const App = ()=>{
  return(
    <div>
      <IDBContextProvider>
        <IDBUpdateComponent />
        <IDBConsumerComponent />
      </IDBContextProvider>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: This helped - pointed me in the right direction. The codebase has major issues with syncing so I needed to work around some debounced save functions and promises, but I wouldn't have solved it without your solution Murli! Thanks.